# Just like (how)

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is the word 'how' appropriately used in the sentence below?

> You do not have some of his abilities, just like **how** not everyone has the strengths you do.

Or should I leave out the 'how'?

> ... just like not everyone has the strength you do.

If 'how' means 'the way that' in constructions like the one above its placement wouldn't make that much sense would it? However, using it makes it sound slightly more natural, but that's just me.

Please explain why you would or would not use it in the example sentence I provided.

Comment: In this particular sentence, this use of ***how*** is optional, and dropping it doesn't have any effect on the semantics of this sentence.

Comment: Which one would you choose to say over the other in everyday conversations?

Comment: Being a non-native speaker it's hard to comment on something like this. But if it's me I would use the version without ***how*** here. Though I might use the other version as well. There is a very slight difference in meaning though, but here in this case the difference has hardly any effect. They both basically mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"How" is unnecessary in that sentence; it feels awkward and doesn't really add anything. The reader is more likely to trip over the word.

We could also swap "like" with "as":

> You do not have some of his abilities, just *as* not everyone has the strengths you do.

Although, using "like" would still be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> You do not have some of his abilities, just like how not everyone has
>   the strengths you do.

In the sentence you are working on, it's "how" that makes it clumsy.

Since the idea is that you don't have what another person has - in the first part of the sentence and that others don't have what you have - in the second, and the situations are both ways *alike*, there obviously is no reason to add "how":

> You do not have some of his abilities like not everyone has the
>   strength you have.

Or

> You do not have some of his abilities like not everyone has your
>   (extraordinary) strength.